# Dynamic IN with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two stored procedure which currently selects from `Users (U)` where U has a booking which matches some criteria (IsPaid = 1 and MonthNo matches that passed to the stored procedure).

**--Users (U)--**

```
UserID      Name
1           John
2           Bill
3           Tom
```

**--Bookings (B)--**

```
BookingID       UserID          MonthNo     IsPaid
5               1               2           1
6               1               3           1
7               1               4           0
8               2               2           1
9               2               3           1
10              2               4           1
11              3               4           1

ALTER PROCEDURE FindUsers...
    @MonthNo
AS
    ...
    WHERE B.IsPaid = 1 AND B.MonthNo = @MonthNo
```

So currently, if `@MonthId` = 3, users #2 and #3 are returned

I now need to pass a list to the procedure to return users where a range of booking match. Ie:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE FindUsers...
    @MonthNosCsv
AS
    ...
    -- split month numbers somehow, then check whether all matching `Booking` rows match.
```

Pseudo code....

```
WHERE ALL(B.IsPaid = 1 AND B.MonthNo IN(CsvSplit(@MonthNoCsv)))
```

So if `@MonthNoCsv` is '2,3,4', only user 2 is returned, because they have paid bookings in months 2,3 and 4.

Is this possible in SQL or would it be best to do secondary processing in the consuming application?

Comment: This link http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html might get you started - but I suspect it requires a level of skill that is beyond your ability to implement. Erland also has a simpler discussion using a CSV string (which is the path you started down) at http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Everyone should have a good splitter.  There are many options available.  I did, however, supply the one I used.

The following list two options, the first is an in-line version, and the second uses a parse function.  Both would return the same results.

**Option 1 - Without a Parse Function**

```
Declare @MonthNoCsv varchar(50) = '2,3,4'

;with cte as (
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@MonthNoCsv,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
)
Select U.*
 from cte M
 Join Bookings B on M.RetVal=B.MonthNo and B.IsPaid=1
 Join Users    U on U.UserID=B.UserID
 Group By U.UserID,U.Name
 Having Count(Distinct B.MonthNo)=(Select max(RetSeq) from cte)
```

**Option 2 - With a Parse Function**

```
Declare @MonthNoCsv varchar(50) = '2,3,4'
;with cte as (
    Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@MonthNoCsv,',')
)
Select U.*
 from cte M
 Join Bookings B on M.RetVal=B.MonthNo and B.IsPaid=1
 Join Users    U on U.UserID=B.UserID
 Group By U.UserID,U.Name
 Having Count(Distinct B.MonthNo)=(Select max(RetSeq) from cte)
```

**Both Return**

```
UserID  Name
2       Bill
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

Comment: "Everyone should have a good splitter" - I disagree. I'd rather everyone switched to using data types *designed* for holding multiple values (tables, xml, json if on 2016 or later) rather than continuing to kludge strings around.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hard to argue that ...  However, I'm sure you've had to consume data from sources beyond your control.  Consider this, even MS "Gave Up" and added Sting_Split() in 2016